# Show dialog in a layout on Android

Tags: android

My ui have 2 LinearLayout, layout1 and layout2.
And use below code to show dialog:

```
private AlertDialog MyDialog;
public void adddialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder MyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    MyBuilder.setTitle("Title")
    MyBuilder .setView(ListView);
    MyDialog = MyBuilder.create();
}
```

I want to set the dialog position on the top-right of layout2.
How can I arrive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private AlertDialog MyDialog;
public void adddialog()
{
  AlertDialog.Builder MyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  MyBuilder.setTitle("Title")
  MyBuilder .setView(ListView);
  MyDialog = MyBuilder.create();
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  WindowManager.LayoutParams dialogParam = MyDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

 dialogParam.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
// dialogParam.x = 100;   //x position
// dialogParam.y = 100;   //y position

 MyDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: But this method show on the screen top-right, not on layout's. The layout's position may not fixed.

Comment: @brian-are you creating layout dynamically?If your layout position is fixed then you can set dialog by using x and y position.

Comment: but as you have post -The layout's position may not fixed.So i also want to know how can dialog be set.!